# How to use XMLStarlet / Xpath to select text inside <div> but exclude some inner <span>

Tags: xml, xpath, text, xmlstarlet

I have such html files.
Basically it has div containing texts with one inner span and the rest text part has pretty arbitrary format.

```
<html>
<div>
<span class="c1">Text1</span><br/>
Text4<br/>
Text5
</div>
<div>
<span class="c1">TextA</span><a href="...">TextD</a>
</div>
</html>
```

it is trivial to select/print only specific text inside span with
`xml sel -t  -m "/html/div" -v "span[@class='c1']" -n`

However I don't know how to select/print the rest text within  but outside the span regardless of any other tags like `<br/>`. The function `text()` does not work as I expect.

`xml sel -t  -m "/html/div" -v "concat(span[@class='c1'],'|',text(),'$')" -n` will cut text behind `<br/>` tags.

how can I get something like

```
Text1|
Text4
Text5$
TextA|TextD$
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while but you said,

> I would like to know if there is a better way than substr method

Here's a version which produces output in document order by using
a template matching the union of desired elements inside an `/html/div`.
Other elements than `br` are output
with their text value followed by a vertical bar. Each `br` element
is output with a newline and the normalized text *following* `br`.
Finally, after 2 `-b`s breaking the `-m` nesting, each `div` is
ended by a dollar sign followed by a newline.

```shell
xmlstarlet sel -T -t \
-m "/html/div" \
  -m 'a | br | span[@class="c1"]' \
  --if 'local-name() = "br"' \
       -n -v 'normalize-space(following-sibling::text())' \
  --else -v '.' -o '|' \
  -b -b -o '$' -n  \
source
```

Output:

```
Text1|
Text4
Text5$
TextA|TextD|$
```

To strip the last `|` before a `$` replace `-o '|'` with
`-v 'substring("|",1,count(following-sibling::*))'`
which emits `|` only if there are more sibling elements.

To  add support for `p` elements, for example, append `| p` to the
2nd `-m` expression and add `<p>Hello from P</p>` to an `/html/div` in the
source file.

(Documentation on `--if … --elif … --else …` is, er, less than copious
but as far as I can make out, from XSLT code output by `-C` option,
the `--if` clause is terminated by `-b`.)

I used `xmlstarlet` 1.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested some xpath's so the best one which I found is

```
//div/descendant-or-self::*/text()[normalize-space()]
```

[image: xpath result]

It indicates the context node and all of its descendants, get text values that aren't empty.

about [XPath axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a better way to do the job, but I have this one. I have tested it in scrapy xpath.I think its help you.

```
print(data.xpath("concat(string(//div[1]/span[contains(@class, 'c1')]),'|', '\n',substring-before(substring-after(//div[1], 'Text1'), 'Text5'),'\n',substring-after(substring-after(//div[1], 'Text1'),'Text4'),'$', '\n',//div[2]/span[contains(@class, 'c1')]/text(),'|',//div[2]/a/text(),'$')").get())
```

output:

```
Text1|
Text4
Text5$
TextA|TextD$
```

Comment: I would like to find a generic way. Text1 and so on are just random example.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I found a solution with `substring-after`

```
xml sel -t  -m "/html/div" -v "span[@class='c1']" -o '|' -v "substring-after(.,span[@class='c1'])" -n
```

but I would like to know if there is a better way than substr method.